# Ionic Capacitor Geolocation is caching position/location. Cannot fetch for new locations

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, geolocation, capacitor

Every time I use the `Geolocation` to **auto locate the device**, it always returns the old position that was located the first time `Geolocation` was used. It seems to be a **caching problem.**
The same problem when I run on `browser or android`. I call the function below to fetch the **coordinates.**

```
import { Plugins, Capacitor } from '@capacitor/core';


    options = {
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0
    };


    public locateUser() {


      Plugins.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.options)
        .then(geoPosition => {
          const coordinates: Coordinates = {
            lat: geoPosition.coords.latitude,
            lng: geoPosition.coords.longitude
          };

          console.log(coordinates.lat , coordinates.lng); // Always prints the old coordinate even if the device is in a different location
        })
        .catch(err => {
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.showErrorAlert();
        });

    }




// I also tried this function below but the same result:

    async getCurrentPosition() {
      const coordinates = await Plugins.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition({
        enableHighAccuracy: true,
        timeout: 10000,
        maximumAge: 0
      });
      alert( coordinates.coords.latitude);
      alert( coordinates.coords.longitude);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Capacitor plugin provides 2 Geolocation objects, `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` and  `Geolocation.watchPosition({}, (position, err)`. In order to constantly watch current user position. You need to use the  `Geolocation.watchPosition({}, (coordinates, err)`. Hence your code should look like:

```
const wait = Geolocation.watchPosition(
    {}, (coordinates, err) => {
     this.Latitude = coordinates.coords.latitude;
     this.Longitude = coordinates.coords.longitude;
})
```